# Interactive mode not supported. Use command exec instead. Connection to localhost closed

Tags: ssh

Instalé y habilité sin problema openssh en windows server 2016, y al momento de tratar de probar desde command prompt ingreso: `ssh Administrator@localhost` y me sale el mensaje:

> Interactive mode not supported. Use command exec instead. Connection to localhost closed.

Alguna idea del porque de este problema. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puede conectar desde otra máquina o con otra user?

Comment: no, no se puede conectar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tenía se solucionó, cambiando de puerto en el que corría el ssh, cambié del 22 al 21, ya que en el puerto 22 se encontraban corriendo procesos de windows y había problemas por esa parte.
Cambie en el archivo C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config , y reinicié el servicio y listo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]